# How to forward https requests to another hosts based on hostname

Tags: apache2

My situation:

I have three ubuntu servers, one NAT router and three domain names and three apache websites. The two domains Ipadress are the WAN ip for the NAT router. All https traffic from internet is forwarded to server one. Every server has his own certificate for his own website.

Someone try to connect:

If the requested hostname is the hostname for website 1. Server 1 shows website 1. 
If the requested hostname is for website 2 or 3. Then server 1 forwards the connection to server 2 or 3. The server 2 or 3 shows website 2 or 3.

Remember server 1 does not have the keys for server 2 or 3.

I have two questions.

1. Is this possible without getting errors like man in the middle.
2. How to edit the apache configuration that this works.

Research:

I searched on google howto forward https requests to another https hosts. Most answers is that server 1 has all the public certificates and keys. and that you need to make an another certificate and key for server 2 or 3. (In my case a self signed certificate). But I don't want that server 1 has the private key for server 2 or 3. Because the public ip for server 1, 2 or 3 is the same it is possible that server 1 does not have the private keys.

I also found how you can have mutiple https virtualhosts on one server with different certificates. No because every server has his own website.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using Apache's [Reverse Proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) feature.  In Server 1's Apache configuration, you would create `VirtualHost` definitions using the hostname's and SSL configs for the sites on Servers 2 and 3, with `ProxyPass` being used to proxy the connections back to those servers via Server 1.

An alternate method would be to run something like NGINX in front of all three servers, have your HTTP/HTTPS traffic NAT'd to NGINX, and configure it to do SSL termination and [reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) for all three servers.

Comment: "Server 1 you create ssl config for server 2 or 3" no because then I also put the private keys for website 2 or 3. See my research section. I want to use a SNI for TLS or something like that. Server 1 must never decrypt the requests for server 2 or 3. Because reserve proxy uses the host header.

Comment: If Server 1 is the only server available to the public Internet using HTTPS, there is no way for it to pretend to be Servers 2 or 3 using HTTPS without having access to Server 2 and 3 SSL keys and certificates.

Comment: But there is a private network (because there is a NAT network). That is why I say it is possible. I can also write a simple program in C++ for this with the openssl library with SNI. Server 1 is just a simple router. It only chamges the destination ip to a private ip.

Comment: Apache and NGINX use SNI to serve multiple SSL sites from distinct certificates on the same IP address, but they must have access to all the keys+certs for each name being used.

Comment: And reserve proxy also changes the source IP to its own ip. No don't do that.

Comment: The original source IP is passed along using the `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header. This is a standard process.

Comment: Okay. I understand. So it isn't possible. Thanks for explanation.